# Checking if word is included in file

Tags: c, string, file

I wrote a function which should check if a word is included in a file, but my function returns always `NOT_EXISTENT`, why? I checked ptr and its always empty but the memory is located.

Here my function:

```
int search_for_word(char wort[]) {
    char *ptr;
    FILE *file;
    unsigned long size_of_file = 0;
    file = fopen("array.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return ERROR;
    }
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size_of_file = ftell(file);
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) *  size_of_file + 1);
    printf("Size:%li\n", size_of_file);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return ERROR;
    }
    fread(ptr, sizeof(char), size_of_file, file);
    if (strstr(ptr, wort) == NULL) {
        return NOT_EXISTENT;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return EXISTENT;
}
```

Comment: The density of your code is perhaps a personal matter of style, but if you expect others to read your code a little vertical/horizontal white-space would go a long way.  You would not be writing code like that on my ream for long - one way or another ;-)

Comment: did you step through this with your debugger, it is a perfect target for doing that

Comment: You forgot to `rewind(file);` (and to check the return value from `fread`). You should also allocate one more byte and write a string terminator before calling `strstr`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Which would have been immediately apparent had there been any error checking - the fact that `fread()` didn't read anything would be known.

Comment: @AndrewHenle best addressed to the person who wrote the code, not me :)

Comment: You should open the file in `"rb"` is you want the code to be portable.  Otherwise on Windows for example `fseek` will produce perhaps surprising results.

Comment: also 0 terminate the buffer or strstr will have UB (you reserved pace for it but didnt set it)

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` always, by definition.  This would be simpler (though less portable) as a memory mapped file perhaps.

Comment: And don't forget to `free(ptr)` too, at both the relevant exit points.

Comment: before `fread` you need to relocate the pointer to the beginning of the file, as you moved it to the end ``fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END)``

Comment: @Clifford 'should open the file in "rb"' depends on how `wort[]` was populated.  Reading the file should be done the same way.

Comment: @Clifford "You would not be writing code like that on my [ream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540799/checking-if-word-is-included-in-file/71541025?noredirect=1#comment126442171_71540799) for long" --> I see we both have spelling/typo troubles. ;-)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica : fair point; the aim is to get the amount of space required for the text, not the length of the file specifically. My error; I stand corrected.

Comment: thank you guys, you helped me really with this. I always forget in other taks  to close the stream when I reopend a file o_o

Answer (score 2):

At least these problems:

**(Biggest issue) Missing rewind** [@alinsoar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540799/checking-if-word-is-included-in-file/71541025#comment126442468_71540799)

`fread()` is attempting a read from the end of the file.  Move back to the beginning.

```
rewind(file); // Add
size_t length = fread(ptr, sizeof(char), size_of_file, file);
```

**Not a *string*** [@pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540799/checking-if-word-is-included-in-file/71541025#comment126442271_71540799)

`ptr` is not certainly a *string* as it may lack a *null character*.  `strstr()` expects 2 strings.

```
strstr(ptr, wort) // bad
```

Instead, append a *null character* to the data read before `strstr()`.

```
size_t length = fread(ptr, sizeof(char), size_of_file, file);
ptr[length] = '\0'; // Add
```

**Failure to close**

Code selectively performs `fclose(file)`.  Call `fclose()` with each successful `fopen()`.

**Missing `free()`** [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540799/checking-if-word-is-included-in-file/71541025#comment126442326_71540799)

Free allocated memory when done.

**`wort[]` may be ill formed**

Posted code does not show the origin of `wort[]`.  So recommendations are guesses at best.

**No check on `fseek()` success**

```
// fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END)
if (fseek(file, 0 /* L not needed */, SEEK_END) == -1) {
  Handle_error();
}
```

**Better with a `const`** [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540799/checking-if-word-is-included-in-file/71541025#comment126442562_71541025)

This allows passing constant strings.

```
// int search_for_word(char wort[]){
int search_for_word(const char wort[]) {
```

**Minor**

Size `sizeof(char) *  size_of_file + 1` may exceed `SIZE_MAX`.

`sizeof(char) *  size_of_file + 1` conceptually wrong.  Better as `sizeof(char) *  (size_of_file + 1)` or just `size_of_file + 1u`.

---

Some rough alternative code - unchecked.

```
// Let calling code open the file
// Return 1 on success.
// Return 0 on no-find.
// Return -1 on other failures. 
int search_for_word(const char *word, FILE *inf) {
  if (inf == 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  size_t length_word = strlen(word);
  if (length_word >= SIZE_MAX / 2) {
    return -1;  // TBD code to handle this extreme case
  }
  size_t buf_size = 4096;  // Adjust as desired
  if (buf_size <= length_word * 2) {
    buf_size = length_word * 2 + 1;
  }
  char *buf = malloc(buf_size);
  if (buf == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  char *in = buf;
  size_t in_length = 0;
  for (;;) {
    size_t length_read = fread(in, 1, buf_size, inf);
    in[length_read] = '\0';
    if (strstr(buf, word)) {
      free(buf);
      return 1;
    }
    if (length_read < buf_size) { // no more data expected
      free(buf);
      return 0;
    }
    // Copy last portion of buffer to the beginning.
    in_length += length_read;
    memmove(buf, &buf[in_length - length_word], length_word);
    in_length = length_word;
    in = buf + in_length;
  }
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough, a mismatched `fopen()`, while sloppy style and certainly to be discouraged, is not an error. The standard says that all streams are flushed and closed on process termination.

Comment: @DevSolar True - hence _problems_, not all _errors_.  Still, lacking a `fclose()`, like a missing `free()`, uses up free-able resources.  Good function house-keeping would put toys away when done, even if the house is to be later destroyed.

Comment: @DevSolar: of course resource leakage only lasts until program exit, but failure to close the stream and/or failure to free the allocated file contents may cause resource exhaustion, which may cause the program to malfunction.

Comment: Clifford suggested opening the file in binary mode to avoid potential issues with `ftell` return value in text mode... This is probably be a good idea, assuming the `wort` does not contain newline characters. OOPS just saw your own comment in this very issue :)

Comment: @chqrlie [Disagree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540799/checking-if-word-is-included-in-file/71541025?noredirect=1#comment126442778_71540799).  If anything, `ftell()` will report as excess offset and suggested fixes here use the return value of `fread()` to determine usable length, not `size_of_file`.  Pedantically the `ftell()` has additional issues, but is nominally tolerable.  IMO, little reason to read entire file and then compare.  Better (albeit more complex) to read portions of the file and then compare.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I'm afraid you are too optimistic: **7.21.9.4 The `ftell` function** [...] *For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the `ftell` call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.* Binary mode seems safer for the full file load method, but I agree that loading the whole file is unnecessary and potentially impractical.

Comment: @chqrlie No so much _too optimistic_ as the seeking to end of a file (binary or text) and then using `ftell()` is, by the book, fought with holes, yet reliable in common practice and is what OP did.  IAC, we (you, me, the spec) all point to one should find an alternative as 1) the _word_ may be found early in a huge file - so why read all? and 2) the file size may exceed memory capacity.  Thus a "read the whole file" approach is not recommended and `fseek()/ftell()` issues disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version implementing suggestions from *chux*'s answer and with an alternative method for huge files (which should probably be used for all files):

```
int search_for_word(const char *wort) {
    int res = NOT_EXISTENT;
    FILE *file = fopen("array.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return ERROR;
    }
#if 0  // set to 1 if you want to load the whole file in memory
    if (fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END) == -1) {
        fclose(file);
        return ERROR;
    }
    long size_of_file = ftell(file);
    if (size_of_file < 0) {
        fclose(file);
        return ERROR;
    }
    rewind(file);
    if ((unsigned long)size_of_file + 1 <= SIZE_MAX) {
        char *ptr = malloc((size_t)size_of_file + 1);
        if (ptr != NULL) {
            size_t length = fread(ptr, 1, size_of_file, file);
            ptr[length] = '\0';
            res = strstr(ptr, wort) ? EXISTENT : NOT_EXISTENT;
            free(ptr);
            fclose(file);
            return res;
        }
    }
#endif
    /* use a different method: read 4KB at a time */
    size_t len = strlen(wort);
    char buf[4096 + len + 1];
    size_t nread, pos = 0;
    while ((nread = fread(buf + pos, 1, 4096, file)) > 0) {
        buf[pos + nread] = '\0';
        if (strstr(buf, wort)) {
            res = EXISTENT;
            break;
        }
        if (pos + nread <= len) {
            pos += nread;
        } else {
            memmove(buf, buf + pos + nread - len, len);
            pos = len;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return res;
}
```